# Missing type despite forward declaration

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a basic factory function that returns a pointer to a forward-declared class, as follows below:

```cpp
#ifndef EQUATION_PLUGIN_HPP
#define EQUATION_PLUGIN_HPP
//! \file equation_plugin.hpp
//  \brief Definition of EquationPlugin

#include <string>

#include <shared_library.hpp>

class Equation;
class PluginManager;

//! ...
class EquationPlugin {
    friend class PluginManager;
  private:
    ...
    PluginManager *manager;
  protected:
    const int nvars;
  public:
    EquationPlugin(int n) : nvars(n) {}
    virtual ~EquationPlugin() = default;
    virtual Equation* CreateEquation() = 0;
};


#endif
```

As you can see, there are two forward declarations: one for `Equation`, and one for `PluginManager`. This seems like a pretty basic thing to me, but for some reason I keep getting the following error from g++:

```
error: ‘Equation’ does not name a type
   31 |     virtual Equation* CreateEquation() = 0;
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting an error with `Equation` but not with `PluginManager`. Sometimes these kinds of issues are caused by circular dependencies, but `equation_plugin.hpp` only has two includes: `string`, which comes from the STL, and `shared_library.hpp`, which is a wrapper around shared library functions that depend only on `dlfcn.h` and `string`. The header file for `PluginManager` does forward declare `EquationPlugin`, but it doesn't make any reference to `Equation`, and the header file for `Equation` is independent of both. Therefore, circular dependencies shouldn't be an issue.

I'm sort of at a loss for what the issue is at this point. Do any of you have any advice for what might be going on?

Comment: When I copy your code and compile it (the test for a [mre] reproducing the error), the compiler complains `shared_library.hpp: No such file or directory`. Commenting out that and the line `...` results in successful compilation. Your example fails to reproduce the error.

Comment: That's sort of the point -- it should compile, but it doesn't.

Comment: @JacobFields The point is that the shown code _does not_ reproduce the error. The problem is in code you haven't shown, which is why you should produce a [mre].

Comment: @JacobFields *"That's sort of the point -- it should compile, but it doesn't."* -- no, the code you posted **does** compile. That's *my* point. If `shared_library.hpp` is needed to reproduce the error, then add a minimal version of `shared_library.hpp` to your question. (Vague descriptions are inadequate.)

Comment: @JaMiT GCC unfortunately produces the shown error message in both cases, if the name is not found at all and if the found name is a non-type.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone. I actually found the issue by renaming `Equation` to something else temporarily and noticing that the error disappeared; it turned out I had an enumerator in a file not linked by any of my code written here, but referenced elsewhere in a source file, with an element labeled `Equation` that unintentionally clashed with my class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The error occurs here in a completely independent source file:

```cpp
...
#include <plugin_manager.hpp>
#include <plugin.hpp>
#include <equation_plugin.hpp>
...
```

The `plugin.hpp` header, which is included before `equation_plugin.hpp` (where `Equation` is forward-declared), defines an enumerator, `PluginType`, which happens to have an element that was called `Equation`. I didn't think about it at the time because the `EquationPlugin` class, prior to refactoring, handled the functionality now present in the `Equation` class. The compiler made it clear that `Equation` was not a type, but it didn't really clarify what `Equation` *was*, nor did it see anything wrong with me trying to forward declare a class with the same name as an enumerator element.

Some things that can be done in the future to avoid these sorts of issues:

1. Pick consistent style conventions that will minimize name clashes between different components of your code; i.e., don't use camel case for your enumerators if you're already using camel case for class names.
2. Don't pollute the global namespace with non-class names if you can avoid it. Hide your non-class functions and enumerators inside namespaces where reasonable.

TL;DR: these sorts of errors can occur if the name of a class clashes with an enumerator or variable elsewhere, and the compiler might not always explain what that name is already reserved for.

Comment: A better approach to avoid name conflicts from enumerators is to use scoped enums (`enum class`) instead. Their enumerator names don't leak into the namespace scope.

Comment: Having a class name clash with a non-type name in the same scope is allowed btw, which is why the compiler doesn't complain about the forward declaration. In such a situation you can disambiguate the type from the non-type name by prefixing the name with `class` or `struct`. E.g. `virtual class Equation* CreateEquation() = 0;` would have worked here.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have other places in my code where I rely on enumerators as array indices, so I left them as regular enumerators or set up a `typedef enum` instead to avoid needing explicit casts everywhere, but this is certainly a situation where scoped enumerators are better.